# Is there a way for Object 1 to call Object 2's enums in a function call?

Tags: java, functions, enum, parameters

For example, if I have two classes "Director" and "Follower". I want the Director to tell the follower where to go (ex: `follower1.go(direction.LEFT)`), and I want the Director to know what directions it can tell the Follower to go when coding in an IDE that gives completion suggestions.

I know I can already either do:

```
public void go(String direction);
```

or

```
public void goLeft();
public void goRight();
public void goUp();
public void goDown();
```

But the first won't give me options in an IDE (or at least, I don't know how to show the options), and the second could be hard to maintain for a less trivial function. Ideally, I would like something like,

```
public enum Direction{LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};
public void go(Direction direction);
```

But of course, that doesn't work (at least in Java, and Direction is part of the Follower class). Is there a roundabout way to use enums (or any other way) to get something like the 3rd effect, where I can both limit the parameters of a function, and make it easily visible in an IDE that gives completion suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* if you remove `public`, it will work:

```
enum Direction{LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};
```

though I believe it that this enum will only be accessible to other classes that are in the same package as `Follower`.

Why does `Direction` need to be contained *within* the `Follower` class, when the `Director` (which I assume is a separate class) will also need to make use of it? If you want to limit the scope of this enum, you could declare it in the same package, but in a separate file. That way you can change it to having `public` scope when you need it to be accessed elsewhere, and the syntax for accessing it is neater and cleaner, too.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know enums could be in their own separate file. That probably solves everything. I don't think removing public works in the case I had though (I had it like that initially, then tried making it public to see if Director could see it). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can with this.

As FrustratedWithFormDesigner pointed out, you can make the enum a top level entity.

The other option is to leave it as a inner-member of one of you classes. To do this, you can either qualify the enum with the host class name:

```
go(Follower.Direction.LEFT);
```

Or you can import the enum and use as you would normally expect:

```
import somepackage.Follower.Direction
...
go(Direction.LEFT);
```

Now, in your case, I would probably suggest going with the top-level enum, as `Direction` doesn't strike me immediately as "belonging" to either `Follower` or `Director`.

---

For completeness, I should mention there's actually a third way to access the enum elements: static imports.  This method should be used judiciously, if at all, but it is something to be aware of.

```
import static somepackage.Direction.*;
....
go(LEFT);
```